# Application not found in google play store app

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-play

I have an application "Kilim Mobilya" in google play store. I have samsung galaxy s3. if I search application on google play application on my phone I can not find it. But if I search google play web site I can find it and it is working. why it is not found in app? my manifest file has these permisions

```
 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />

     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

I can install apk on phones but I can not install on tablet. what should I do for installing on every device? What should my min sdk be?  thanks good work.

Answer (score 2):

your `android:minSdkVersion="15"` is wa-aaay too high. try to make it lower.

on the web page of your application, there should be a list of your devices, clearly marked if this application is compatible with the device or not. try to see, if your tables is in that list. most probably not, because of "Requires Android: 4.0.3 and up" in your application listing.

Comment: when I search on computer Below the app on web site it says you have no device.Is it normal?

Comment: you should have a google account, and devices registered to that account. if you don't, they won't be listed. anyway, lower the `minSDKVersion` to 9 or maybe 10, and most your problems will go away.